# How to pass all system properties to test task in gradle kotlin dsl?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

How do I convert this gradle groovy snippet to gradle kotlin dsl without being very verbose?

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties() 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with this...

```
tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    systemProperties System.getProperties() as Map<String, Any>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The least verbose way I found is:

```
tasks.test {
    systemProperties(System.getProperties().mapKeys { it.key as String })
}
```

[Test#systemProperties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:systemProperties) expects a `Map<String, Object>` but [System#getProperties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) returns a `java.util.Properties` object so that still needs to be converted.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer here is close but is missing an equal sign:

```
tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    systemProperties = System.getProperties() as Map<String, Any>
}
```

another similar option would be:

```
tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    systemProperties = System.getProperties() as Map<String, Any>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
test {
    systemProperties(System.getProperties().map { it.key.toString() to it.value }.toMap())
}
```